# Get window, document and body in Electron 5+ remote.BrowserWindow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Currently, electron 5.0 removed the ability to use `nativeWindowOpen` with `nodeIntegration`, so it's impossible to use `ReactDOM.createPortal` on the document.body returned by `window.open`. They didn't put any workaround, and I've tried everything found in other answers, like:

- IPC back the DOM node to the `new remote.BrowserWindow`, it doesn't send back a valid DOM node to attach to
- `webContents.executeJavascript`, with either `(function(){ return window })()` document or body, makes the process hang

I just don't seem to be able to do the equivalent using BrowserWindow:

```
// this is what works in Electron 4 with a warning see https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/15193
const container = window.open("about:blank", "someuniqueid"); // window = current main window

const stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
stylesheet.rel = 'stylesheet';
stylesheet.href = document.querySelector('link').href; // document = current main window

container.document.body.appendChild(stylesheet);
// [... edited for brevity]
return createPortal(
  props.children(container), // children = render props, pass the window to the children
  container.document.body
)
```

nothing is able to return a valid DOM node from the created window. `require('electron')` also doesn't work for obvious reasons (nodeIntegration is always disabled)